# Images from Backstretch(backstretch.js) in onepage creeping in to other page's backstretch in Durandal.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, durandal, jquery-backstretch

I have used Durandal.js for my SPA. I need to have slideshow of Images as background in certain pages, for which I am using jquery-backstretch. I am fetching images from my web back-end. Everything works fine while navigating between pages in normal speed. But, when I navigate from one of the pages which has backstretch to another one with backstretch very rapidly, Images from backstretch in first page also creeps in second page. When I debugged, only the correct Images were being passed to second page. And also the slideshow is not running in a proper interval. So it must be both the backstretches being invoked.

Please tell me how I can stop the previous backstretch from appearing again. Here are the relevant code snippets.

This is my first page's(with backstretch) viewmodel code.

```
var id = 0;
var backstetcharray;
function loadbackstretchb() {
backstetcharray = new Array();
$.each(that.products, function (i, item)
{

    if(item.ProductBackImage != "")
    {
        backstetcharray.push("xxxxxxxxxx" + item.ProductBackImage);
    }

}
);
$.backstretch(backstetcharray, { duration: 5000, fade: 1500 });
}
var that;
define(['plugins/http', 'durandal/app', 'knockout'], function (http, app, ko) {
var location;
function callback() {
    window.location.href = "#individual/"+id;
    // this.deactivate();
};
return {
    products: ko.observableArray([]),
    activate: function () {
        currentpage = "products";
        that = this;
        return http.get('yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy').then(function (response) {
            that.products = response;
            loadbackstretchb();
        });

    },
    attached: function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.contacticon').on({
            'mouseenter': function () {
                $(this).animate({ right: 0 }, { queue: false, duration: 400 });
            },
            'mouseleave': function () {
                $(this).animate({ right: -156 }, { queue: false, duration: 400 });
            }
        });
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".mainmenucont").effect("slide", null, 1000);
        });
        //setTimeout($(".mainmenucont").effect("slide", null, 1000), 1000);

        $(document).on("click", ".ind1", function (e) {
           // alert("ind1");
            id = e.target.id;
           // $(".mainmenucont").effect("drop", null, 2000, callback(e.target.id));
            $('.mainmenucont').hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000, callback);
        });
    }
}
});
```

This  is my second page's(with backstretch) viewmodel code.(To where I am navigating)

```
var recs;
var open;
var i, count;
var backstetcharray;
function loadbackstretchc() {
backstetcharray = new Array();
$.each(recs, function (i, item) {

    if (item.BackgroundImage != "") {
        backstetcharray.push("xxxxxxxxxx" + item.BackgroundImage);
    }

}
);
$.backstretch(backstetcharray, { duration: 5000, fade: 1500 });
}
var that;
define(['plugins/http', 'durandal/app', 'knockout'], function (http, app, ko) {
var system = require('durandal/system');
var location;
function menucallback() {
    window.location.href = location;
    // this.deactivate();
};


return {
    activate: function (val) {
        currentpage = "recipes";
        open = val;
       that = this;
        var pdts;
        recs;
        var recipeJson = [];
         http.get('yyyyyyyyyyyyyy').then(function (response) {
            pdts = response;
            http.get('yyyyyyyyyyyy').then(function (response1) {
                recs = response1;
                loadbackstretchc();
                $.each(pdts, function (i, item) {
                    var json = [];
                    $.each(recs, function (j, jtem) {
                        if (item.DocumentTypeId == jtem.BelongstoProduct) {
                            json.push(jtem);
                        }
                    });

                    jsonitem = {}
                    jsonitem["product"] = item.ProductName;
                    jsonitem["link"] = "#" + item.UmbracoUrl;
                    jsonitem["target"] = item.UmbracoUrl;
                    jsonitem["recipes"] = json;
                    recipeJson.push(jsonitem);

                });

                // that.products = recipeJson;
                count = recipeJson.length;
                i = 0;
                return that.products(recipeJson);

            });
        });
    },
    attached: function(view) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.contacticon').on({
                'mouseenter': function () {
                    $(this).animate({ right: 0 }, { queue: false, duration: 400 });
                },
                'mouseleave': function () {
                    $(this).animate({ right: -156 }, { queue: false, duration: 400 });
                }

            });



        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".mainmenucont").effect("slide", null, 1000);
        });

        $(document).on("click", ".recipeclick", function (e) {
            console.log(e);
            location = "#recipe/" + e.target.id;
            $('.mainmenucont').hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000, menucallback);
        });



        $(document).on("click", ".locclick", function (e) {
            if (e.handled != true) {
                if (false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
                    $('#accordion ul').slideUp(300);
                }
                $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
                e.handled = true;
            }
        });
    },
    products: ko.observableArray([]),
    expand: function() {
        ++i;
        if (i == count) {
            $("#" + open).addClass("in");

        }
    }
};

});
```

Comment: There are many problems with your code: it is not written in the spirit of Durandal.  We don't use `document.ready`, for example.  This code should be placed in the `compositionComplete` event handler that Durandal exposes on each view.  Also, all of your `vars` are leaking.  I would suggest starting with John Papa's Hot Towel template for Durandal.

Comment: @EricTaylor Thank You for your directions. I will definitely follow that tutorial. I am a newbie and this is my first project. Can you please point out in particular, what might be causing this issue ? I have to submit this soon.

Comment: There are many things wrong in what you're doing.  I would have to rewrite all of your code.  I would say that you should take some time to get familiar with the framework you're using.

Comment: Hi @Sreeraj Did you manage to fix the other images coming in? I'm facing the same problem when rapidly changing pages and updating the backstretch object. I think it only happens when using slideshows..